# 'WebdatarocksPivotModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, module, ivy

when importing WebdatarocksPivotModule in the app.module.ts i'm getting 'WebdatarocksPivotModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
i am using angular 16

i tried disabling ivy
"enableIvy": false
and dongrading to angular 15